# GA API: Request a new refresh token with valid access token

Tags: google-api, refresh, token, google-analytics-api

I came into an app that didn't handle google analytics api omniauth revoke correctly and now I have a slew of users that have revoked their information and when reauthorizing our app don't get the the permission window as our app is already approved.

The issue I'm having is that when they "reauthorize" with out asking for permission I receive a valid access token but the refresh token doesn't come with it.  That is understandable as that parameter is only sent on initial permission grant.

Is it possible to create a curl request for a GA refresh token with a valid access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force reauthorization, you can set the `approval_prompt` parameter to `force`. You also need to set the `access_type` parameter to `offline` to get a new refresh token.